# Is it possible to pass two (2) values from 1 radio button when clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, radio-button

I have here a numerous amount of radio buttons and their values are taken from a database. I want to add the type of leave but I can't figure it out. To make myself more clear, once the "Sick" radio button is clicked and when pressing the submit button, the "Sick" credits or the available hours for Sick leave (The value of my radio button which is the (value=$sLeave) and at the same time, the type of leave which is the Sick leave (Hidden type) will be passed to the next page.

I tried this one in every type of leave:

```
 if($sLeave!=0)
 {
 ?> 

<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $sLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Sick">Sick</label>
    <input type="hidden" name"leaveType" value="Sick" />

<?php
} 
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label  for="Sick">Sick</label>

<?php
}
?>
```

BUT all of the type of leave will be passed to the next page and it outputs the last hidden value. Not the one that is selected.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="leaveForm" name="lform" method="get" action="leaveFiled.php" />

if($sLeave!=0)
{
?>  
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $sLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Sick">Sick</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Sick">Sick</label>


<?php
}
?>

<?php
if($vLeave!=0)
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $vLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Vacation">Vacation</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Vacation">Vacation</label>

<?php
}
?>

<?php                   
if($eLeave!=0)
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $eLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Emergency">Emergency</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Emergency">Emergency</label>

<?php
}
?>

<?php                   
if($mLeave!=0 && $sex=='F')
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $mLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Maternity">Maternity</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Maternity">Maternity</label>

<?php
}
?>

<?php                   
if($pLeave!=0 && $sex=='M')
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $pLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Paternity">Paternity</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Paternity">Paternity</label>

<?php
}
?>

<?php                   
if($uLeave!=0)
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $uLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Union">Union</label>

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" /><label for="Union">Union</label>

<?php
}
?>

<?php                   
if($oLeave!=0)
{
?>

<tr>
<td height="40" colspan="3" align="left">
    <strong>
    <input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo $oLeave; ?>" onclick="enableTextarea()" />    
    <label for="Other Leave">Other Leave</label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label for="Reason of Leave">Reason of Leave:</label>
    <input type="text" name="reasonLeave" size="35" disabled="disabled" />        
    </strong> 
</td>
</tr> 

<?php
}
else
{
?>
<tr>
<td height="40" colspan="3" align="left">
    <strong>
    <input type="radio" name="optLeave" disabled="disabled" />
    <label for="Other Leave">Other Leave</label>
    </strong>
</td>
</tr> 

<?php
}                       
?>
```

Maybe the use of javascript may solve this problem but I'm hoping for another solution to this.

Comment: When you mark a element as disabled then that element does not become part of post data.

Comment: Thanks @Rajan for the response. The radio button will be disabled only once the credit of an specific leave type has fall to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use diffrent prefix with unique separator like underscore(*) or colon(:) whatever u want in values eg. sleave* for sick leave or else

```
<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo "sleave_".$sLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Sick">Sick</label>

<input type="radio" name="optLeave" value="<?php echo "uleave_".$uLeave; ?>" onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Union">Union</label>
```

then in post u can separate the value by explode function and you will get the your values.

```
//use same separator here
$opt_leave = explode("_", $_REQUEST['optLeave']);
$leave_type = $opt_leave[0];
$leave = $opt_leave[1];
//now you can use $leave_type to check your conditions by switch or if conditional statements

if($leave_type == 'sleave') {
  // action on sick leave
} else if($leave_type == 'uleave') {
 // action on Union leave
}
```

Comment: Sir, can you help me with something? I got a huge feeling that you got the solution to my problem. Hoping for your response.

Comment: oh ya sure , pls tell me ur problem.

Comment: Please check this. http://jsfiddle.net/dKCUy/1/ -> I wanted my program to work like that with 2 values on my radio button. I'm a newbie with Javascript and I have no idea how to implement such thing with the use of JS. I got my js code from an auto calculation code and tweaked some parts thats why i was able to get it. Since the value of my radio button has 2 values already (value="<?php echo "Sick_".$sLeave; ?>"). It will return NaN instead of an integer. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, its working. Hope this is working as you want. pls check ur link.

Comment: Did you tweaked the code in the link? I viewed the link but it's all the same as what I've posted.

Comment: Yup that link works but try to check the HTML Code. '<input type="radio" name="optLeave" **value="40"** onclick="disableTextarea()" /><label for="Sick">Sick</label>'. I'm going to change the value with **value="<?php echo "Sick_".$sLeave; ?>"**. It doesnt work anymore. PHP code doesnt work in fiddle thats why I changed the value to an integer. My **$sLeave** has a value of integer that is taken from the database. The **Sick_** is the type of leave.​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I not found d changes that i have done, I changed <?php echo $pLeave; ?> to Paternity_50 and <?php echo $uLeave; ?> to uleave_35 and after that I wrote the some js in this if block. `if((e = getChecked('optLeave', this.form, 'radio'))) { `

Comment: You should've clicked update after changing the codes then share the link here.. hehe. Thanks Sir @ShahidAhmed for helping :)